# Ошибка: "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вроде бы написал Всё правильно должна из текстбокса вводить в переменную qb а потом выводить в окне

```
import os
from tkinter import *

MyGUIinterface = Tk()
qp = StringVar()
po = (qp)
vsd = os.listdir(po)

MyGUIinterface.title("LSTIR Pratotype")

MyGUIinterface.geometry('600x500')

txt = Entry(MyGUIinterface, textvariable = qp ,width=50)
txt.grid(column=2, row=0)


def clicked():
    folderpath = Label(MyGUIinterface, text = vsd)





btn = Button(MyGUIinterface, text="enter the folder path and click me", 
commnd = clicked )

btn.grid(column = 0, row=0)

MyGUIinterface.mainloop()
```

Это исправленный код Я попытался исправить теперь выдает другую ошибка ошибка Он ошибку

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'PY_VAR0'

Comment: Давайте я скопирую текст ошибки в Google Translate за вас: "путь должен быть строкой, байтами os.PathLike или None, а не StringVar"

Comment: Так что я должен делать? Чтобы это исправить

Comment: Пожалуйста ответь

Comment: я подредактировал код, И вот что получилось...

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Функция `os.listdir()` ожидает, что в нее передадут что-то похожее на строку (если буквально по тексту ошибки - строку, байты, `os.PathLike` или `None`). Объект `StringVar` (несмотря на `string` в названии) сам по себе не является строкой. Но в него можно положить строку (методом `.set()`) или получить из него строку (методом `.get()`). Исправление для исходной ошибки. Т.е. чтобы получить строку из объекта `qp` нужно выполнить `s = qp.get()`. См. пример кода здесь: [**Coupling Widget Variables**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables).
2. В тот момент, когда у вас в коде стоит `listdir`, объект `qp` только что создан и содержит пустую строку. Нет смысла выполнять `listdir` в этот момент. Нужно его выполнять в момент нажатия на кнопку. Также неплохо было бы обрабатывать ошибки, если ничего не введено, путь не существует, и т.д.
3. Создаваемый при нажатии на кнопку объект `Label` вы не размещаете в окне (методом `grid`). Объект создастся, но в окне не будет отображаться
4. Объект `Label` не поддерживают многострочный текст, поэтому список файлов выведется в одну строку.

Код с учетом всех исправлений:

```
import os
from tkinter import *

MyGUIinterface = Tk()
qp = StringVar()

MyGUIinterface.title("LSTIR Pratotype")

MyGUIinterface.geometry('600x500')

txt = Entry(MyGUIinterface, textvariable = qp ,width=50)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)


def clicked():
    vsd = os.listdir(qp.get())
    folderpath = Label(MyGUIinterface, text = vsd)
    folderpath.grid(columnspan=2)


btn = Button(MyGUIinterface, text="enter the folder path and clickme",command = clicked )

btn.grid(column = 0, row=0)

MyGUIinterface.mainloop()
```

Также исправлена опечатка в названии параметра `command`

Comment: Спасибо большое Ты меня спас!